# OpenCV vs ImageJ which one to chose if you want to develop in Java?

Tags: java, opencv, imagej

I would like to use a library to detect objects in an image such as a chair, a bed... Which library would you recommend `OpenCV` or `ImageJ`?

Comment: [StackOverflow is not a Recommendation Engine](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/134915/162852).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ImageJ seems applicable only to image processing, not on actually recognising anything.